# Grant third party application to read/write files created by my application using content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, file-permissions

I am creating an simple application that downloads and saves documents from the server to the SDCard root folder. I am able to do this successfully. 
Now I want another application of mine to read/edit files created before using content providers. I am trying to share the files/folders through providers but when I try to create new RandomAccessFile  at the shared folder location it gives Permission error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/8539-1916/Folder: at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
04-21 04:36:44.493  6118  9673 E TAG    : Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-21 04:36:44.493  6118  9673 E TAG    :      at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-21 04:36:44.493  6118  9673 E TAG    :      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
04-21 04:36:44.493  6118  9673 E TAG    :      at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
```

Can someone help me with an example of how we can share folder to another application to write/reads files through content providers?

Comment: "I am able to do this successfully" -- not on many devices. We have not had reliable access to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) since Android 4.4. And that's on top of the new limitations on external and removable storage added in Android 10. "Can someone help me with an example" -- https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information, so my application signed as a system-level application using android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system", which made my 1st application to write in SDCard. Does the limitation applies to system signed application as well??

Comment: I can't answer that -- for that `sharedUserId` to work, your app would need to be signed by the firmware signing key. Whoever set up that firmware should know what the rules are with respect to removable storage on that device.

Comment: Could take a look at this https://android.jlelse.eu/system-app-in-android-f003d418b4cc
This might help you. It's about system app in Android and use of sharedUserId.